# Fragments and view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am building an android app, which is meant for giving feedback for a set of questions.The no of questions vary each time depending on the server data.The fragment and the view pager is working fine for other no of questions but not for single question.Do i have to handle the position=0 condition as shown in the below code ?

```
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            pos = position;
            if (position == (viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1)) {
                nextRipple.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                submitRipple.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                nextRipple.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                submitRipple.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (position == 0) {
                priviousRipple.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                priviousRipple.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have three buttons "previous","next" and "submit"................submit button should be visible only at the last question and rest of the questions will have next button to navigate over the questions.

Answer (score 0):

For easier process, you will only judge if the position is on first or on last item. Like this one:

```
if (position == 0) {
    priviousRipple.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    nextRipple.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else if (position == (viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1)) {
    priviousRipple.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    nextRipple.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    submitRipple.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    priviousRipple.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    nextRipple.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir.It is working fine for any number of questions.But it is still not working for single question.I want the fragment to show "submit" button directly when only one question is fetched from server as it is the only question to be answered and submitted.

Comment: I see. In that case you will add a variable that records the number of question from server. Then if `numQuestions.size == 1` then make your `submitRipple` button visible. You will add it outside the `onPageSelected()` function.